# In Shopify, how do i get the logged in user information of admin section?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to track the actions taken by the logged-in user in Shopify admin.

If a shop has multiple staff with admin access, how can I get the information of which staff/user is currently logged in?

It can be either via API or from JS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a log of actions by staff in Shopify Admin. You can see when staff was last logged in (Shopify Admin > Settings > Accounts), but you won't be able to track what they are doing.

You can see some activity through `/admin/activity` but it's very limited.

However, there are available apps that can track those for you. You can checkout [Staffy](https://apps.shopify.com/staffy) or [Logify](https://apps.shopify.com/activity-logs).